# How to Compare response data from Oracle and Cloud in Jmeter

Tags: java, oracle, jmeter, compare, cloud

My Application was moving to cloud now, So we are planning to compare response data from ***Oracle*** and ***Cloud*** implementation.

We are getting Response data as Json, So Any have idea about how to compare both?

We are planning to Automate the comparison process not in Manual. So give me some suggestion for this.

Comment: To compare the response, you need to add Comparison Assertion Visualizer and make sure that you added in the appropriate place. 
http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Comparison_Assertion_Visualizer

Comment: It looks good, But may i know how to give both request or response here to compare?

Comment: You need to use Compare Assertion and then Comparison Assertion Visualizer. I will post the snapshots soon. Thanks!